# Angular Leaflet directive - reproduce layer example

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

How can I reproduce [this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control-example.html) example with the angular Leaflet directive?
I understand the example, but when I apply the last line of the example source

```
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

that I had to adjust to

```
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo($scope);
```

Because all map properties are in $scope now...?

```
angular.extend($scope,{
                 defaults: {
                        layers: [streetLayer,sateliteLayer,oceanLayer],
                        maxZoom: 16,
                        zoomControl: false,
                        doubleClickZoom: true,
                        path: {
                            weight: 10,
                            color: '#800000',
                            opacity: 1
                        }
                 }
            });
```

I get

```
TypeError: this._map.on is not a function
    at o.Control.Layers.o.Control.extend._initLayout (leaflet.js:9)
    at o.Control.Layers.o.Control.extend.onAdd (leaflet.js:9)
    at o.Control.o.Class.extend.addTo (leaflet.js:9)
    at new <anonymous> (mapController.js:135)
    at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:12884)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:12892)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17161
    at self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:48243)
    at Object.switcher.render (ionic.bundle.js:46441)
    at Object.switcher.init (ionic.bundle.js:46361)
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker/jsfiddle or something similar for me to take a look?

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea how to integrate leaflet and ionic into jsfiddle or similar...